# Form alter overriding submitted values

Tags: 7, forms

I have a form_form_id_alter function that sets some default values and a checkbox checked.

If I submit the form, with the checkbox unset and it fails validation, the re-rendered form re-sets the checkbox to a checked state (as per the form_alter), not the submitted state.

Is this expected behaviour? I would expect the submitted values to remain persistant.

Do I need to re-assign the submitted values in the form_validate function or am I doing something wrong?

I'm using this function to alter form:

```
// Form ID alter
function events_form_registration_event_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  global $user;

  $form['#validate'][] = 'events_form_registration_event_node_form_validate';

  // If node add.
  if(arg(1) == 'add'){

    // Check if the user is an event editor and perform the form_alter
    if(events_does_user_have_role($user)){

      // Show end date, checkbox value checked
      $form['field_show_end_date'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';

      // Event status, list value Open
      $form['field_event_status'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#default_value'] = 'Open';

    }
  }
}


// Validate form.
function events_form_registration_event_node_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state){

  // Get the current end date value from submitted form.
  $current_end_date_value = ($form_state['values']['field_show_end_date'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']);


  // Set the show_end_date element to have the submitted value.
  $form['field_show_end_date'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#attributes']['checked'] = $current_end_date_value ;

}
```

Comment: post your code, what have you tried so far ?

Comment: what is the name of your module ?

Comment: form_registration_event I've renamed it here for privacy reasons. I have debugged in PHP Storm and I can see the function being called.

Comment: I've updated code with latest code version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check values of checkbox field in *$form_state* while setting it "checked" in line

```
$form['field_show_end_date'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';
```

This would be something like

```
$form['field_show_end_date'][LANGUAGE_NONE]['#attributes']['checked'] = isset($form_state['values']['field_show_end_date'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']) ? $form_state['values']['field_show_end_date'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] : 'checked';
```

I haven't tested this code, but it should work just fine or it will give you idea about how to fix your problem. Hope it helps...cheers!

Comment: Thanks @RajeevK However, it looks like $form_state is not available in my form_alter_function.

Comment: @BearWithNoHair It won't be available initially, but when validation fails and again alter is called, there should be data in it.